# Hyperbolic space and isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

This is [Lemma 1.4.4](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA9) from Scharlau's book *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms*.

> Let $GL(V)=Aut(V)$ denote the group of invertible endomorphisms of $V$. Further one can check that $$\mathbb H \colon GL(V) \to O(\mathbb H(V)), \qquad \alpha\to \alpha\oplus(\alpha^*)^{-1}$$ is an injective group homomorphism.

[image]

$H$ is hyperbolic space on $V$ and one can define bilinear form on this like below:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $V^*$ its dual space. On the vector space $V\oplus V^*$ we consider the following symmetric bilinear form:
>   \begin{gather*}
> h=h_V\colon (V\oplus V^*)\times(V\oplus V^*) \to K\\
> h((x,f),(y,g)):= fy+gx
> \end{gather*}

[image]

Also, I know from this lemma that

> **4.4. Lemma.** Let $\alpha\colon V\to W$ be a vector space isomorphism and $\alpha^*\colon W^*\to V^*$ be the dual isomorphism. Then
>   $$\mathbb H(\alpha):= \alpha\oplus(\alpha^*)^{-1} \colon \mathbb H(V) \to \mathbb H(V)$$ is a bijective isometry.

[image]

Question is how to show it is an injective group homomorphism. First of all how to show $O(H(V))$ is a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why is $O(\mathbb H(V))$ a group?* If you already know that $\mathbb H(V)=(V\oplus V^*, \mathbb h_V)$ is a bilinear space, then this follows from the fact that $O(V,b)$ is a group for any bilinear space $(V,b)$.

*$\mathbb H(\alpha)$ belongs to $O(\mathbb H(V))$.* The fact that $\mathbb H(\alpha)\in O(\mathbb H(V))$ for $\alpha\in GL(V)$ is exactly the claim in Proposition 4.4.

*$\mathbb H$ is a group homomorphism.* We just want to show that $\mathbb H(\beta\circ\alpha)=\mathbb H(\beta)\circ \mathbb H(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha,\beta\in GL(V)$. We just compute
\begin{align*}
(\beta\circ\alpha)\oplus ((\beta\circ\alpha)^*)^{-1}
&= (\beta\circ\alpha)\oplus (\alpha^*\circ\beta^*)^{-1} \\
&= (\beta\circ\alpha)\oplus ((\beta^*)^{-1}\circ(\alpha^*)^{-1}) \\
&= (\beta,(\beta^*)^{-1})\circ(\alpha,(\alpha^*)^{-1})
\end{align*}

*$\mathbb H$ is injective.* It suffices to check that $\mathbb H$ has trivial kernel. Clearly, $$\mathbb H(V)=\alpha\oplus(\alpha^*)^{-1}=id_V\oplus id_{V^*}$$
implies $\alpha=id_V$.

Comment: How the third step in homomorphism  is true?

Comment: By "the third step" do you mean $(\beta\circ\alpha)\oplus ((\beta^*)^{-1}\circ(\alpha^*)^{-1}) = (\beta,(\beta^*)^{-1})\circ(\alpha,(\alpha^*)^{-1})$?

Comment: yes that step only.

Comment: Is it just component wise breaking of direct sum?

Comment: Perhaps (depending on your notation and on how you interpret $\oplus$) you might prefer the notation $\beta\oplus(\beta^*)^{-1}$ instead of $(\beta,(\beta^*)^{-1})$.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak why alpha is isometry in lemma 4.4 I can it is bijective since alpha and alpha * is isomorphism but how to show it is isometry

Comment: @Ninjahatori I have left some comments on this in the [linear algebra chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/75088/2018/7/14).